# Mysql IF NOT EXISTS then select

Tags: mysql, not-exists

i try to select all rows "labels" from a table by parent_id and language.
Default language is en.

```
list = SELECT * FROM labels WHERE parent_id = x AND lang='de'

if( list.isEmpty() ){
   list = SELECT * FROM labels WHERE parent_id = x AND lang='en'
}
```

how to handle this using only one MySQL Statement?

many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try,

```
SELECT  *
FROM    labels
WHERE   parent_id = x AND
        lang = 
        (
            SELECT  lang
            FROM    labels
            WHERE   parent_id = x
            ORDER   BY FIELD(lang, 'en', 'de') DESC
            LIMIT   1 
        )
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4120/1)

The [FIELD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function returns the index of string in the list.

Here's using `JOIN`

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.*
FROM    labels a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  parent_id, lang
            FROM    labels
            WHERE   parent_id = 1
            ORDER   BY FIELD(lang, 'en', 'de') DESC
            LIMIT   1 
        ) b ON a.parent_id = b.parent_id AND
                a.lang = b.lang
WHERE   a.parent_id = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4120/2)

Comment: thanks, this does exactly what i am looking for, however, is it not better(faster) using join instead of 2 selects? if joiun better, how to rewrite your solution above using join?

Comment: no, not this way. the idea behind using join is to avoid multi Selects, i find your first solution is still better than join and 2 selects. i will use the first one and accept your answer. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use `where not exists` and `union all`:

```
SELECT * FROM labels WHERE parent_id = x AND lang='de'
union all
SELECT *
FROM labels
WHERE parent_id = x AND lang = 'en' and
      not exists (SELECT * FROM labels WHERE parent_id = x AND lang='de')
```